# Why does my app create multiple sockets from the same server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a server running in the front end, and one in the back end. The front-end server is localhost:8080 and the back-end is localhost:3000.

Here is my back-end server file:

```
import express from 'express';
import socket from 'socket.io';

const app = express();

const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});

const io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);

  socket.on('chat', (data) => {
    io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
  });

  socket.on('typing', (data) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
  });
});
```

And here is the front-end server:

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

const send = '#send',
      message = '#message',
      name = '#name',
      output = '#output',
      status = '#status'

$(send).click(() => {
  socket.emit('chat', {
    message: $(message).val(),
    name: $(name).val()
  });
});

$(message).keypress(() => {
  socket.emit('typing', $(name).val());
});

socket.on('chat', (data) => {
  $(status).html('');
  $(output).append('<p><strong>' + data.name + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>');
});

socket.on('typing', (data) => {
  $(status).html('<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message...</em></p>');
});
```

In the front end whenever I open a new tab and visit localhost:8080 a new socket is created and the 'made socket connection' message appears. This confused me because it was my understanding that there was one 'socket' per server.

Comment: the `made socket connection` will log every time a new user connects/reconnects to the webpage

Answer (score 0):

No, in socket.io you have one `connection` callback and for every new connection, a new `socket` object will be created and stored, so you can emit and receive messages with many different sockets in the `connection` callback body!